# Angular: Add component by clicking checkbox and delete component by unclicking it

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am new to angular and am currently working on a **ticket booking system**. There, I need to **add passengers according to the needs** of the `user`. In the booking `component`, there is a **form component** where passenger details are entered.

I want to **add** a `button`(add another passenger) in the **form component** such that when it is **clicked**, *the application generates another form component for the user to add another passenger's details*.

Along with the passenger add button, I am thinking of adding a **passenger remove button** that removes the passenger and the corresponding forms component.
**I don't want the new component to be a child of the previous forms component** so that in case, if we have total of 5 passengers and I delete the passenger 2, that does not delete all the passengers from 2 to 5.

**booking.component.html**

```
<form id="bookingForm">
    <label for="pName">Passenger Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="pName" name="pName"><br><br>
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age"><br><br>
    <label for="addPassenger"> Add Passenger</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="addPassenger" name="addPassenger" value={{passengerCount}}>
    <button (click)="addPassenger()">Add Passenger</button>
    <button (click)="removePassenger()">Remove Passenger</button>
</form>

<input type="submit" value="Confirm" form="bookingForm">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make a `function` in your `component` that **add** or **remove** new passenger *from  array of passengers*.

In **HTML**, you will use **ngFor** to add new passenger in your form.

You can see it done here

[Angular 6 Dynamically Add Rows Reactive Forms](https://blog.karmacomputing.co.uk/angular-6-dynamically-add-rows-reactive-forms-how-to/)